# Using geom_path from ggplot library

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have 12 variables, ***M1, M2, ..., M12***, for which I compute a certain statistic ***x***.

```
 df = data.frame(model = factor(paste("M", 1:28, sep = ""), levels=paste("M", 1:28, sep = "")), x = runif(28, 1, 1.05))

 levels = seq(0.8, 1.2, 0.05)
```

I would like to plot this data as follows:

[image]

Each circle (contour) represents the a level of that statistic ***"x"***. The three blue lines simply represent three different scenarios.

The dataframe included in this example represents one scenario. The blue line would simply join the values of all the models ***M1*** to ***M28*** for that specific scenario.

I tried the following:

```
 ggplot(data=df, aes(x=model, y=x, group=1)) + 
   geom_line() + coord_polar() + 
   scale_y_continuous(limits=range(levels), breaks=levels, labels=levels) +
   theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank())
```

However, I get a disconnected path (between M28 and M1)

[image]

Then, I replicated the first row and placed it at the bottom of the dataframe (see below), and then used `geom_path()` instead of `geom_line()`, but I didn't get the result I was looking for:

```
 ## Replicating the first row (model1) and placing it at end of dataframe
 df = rbind(df, df[1,])

 ## using geom_path()

 ggplot(data=df, aes(x=model, y=lg, group=1)) + 
   geom_path() + coord_polar() + 
   scale_y_continuous(limits=range(levels), breaks=levels, labels=levels) +
   theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.title.x =  element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank())
```

[image]

Could any please help me achieve the result that I am looking for? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use `geom_polygon` for closed paths:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=model, y=x, group=1)) + 
  geom_polygon(fill = NA, colour = "black") + 
  coord_polar() + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits=range(levels), breaks=levels, labels=levels) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank(), 
        axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: +1 @Mariam, sorry for the misleading comment in your earlier question; I hadn't actually tried it and assumed it would work.

Comment: @BrodieG no worries! You were very helpful despite that!

Comment: Sven, for some reason, I still get the same result as using geom_path()... I don't know why..

Comment: @Mariam I just the first version of `df` *before* the `rbind` command.