# Adding an additional point to ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

This question is a follow-up to this post: [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21531230/using-geom-path-from-ggplot-library)

I have 28 variables, ***M1, M2, ..., M28***, for which I compute certain statistics ***x*** and ***y***.

```
 library(ggplot2)
 df = data.frame(model = factor(paste("M", 1:28, sep = ""), levels=paste("M", 1:28, sep = "")), a = runif(28, 1, 1.05), b = runif(28, 1, 1.05))

 levels = seq(0.8, 1.2, 0.05)
```

Here is the plot:

```
 ggplot(data=df) + 
   geom_polygon(aes(x=model, y=a, group=1), color = "black", fill = NA) + 
   geom_polygon(aes(x=model, y=b, group=1), color = "blue", fill = NA) +
   coord_polar() + 
   scale_y_continuous(limits=range(levels), breaks=levels, labels=levels) +
   theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank())
```

I would like to add a point the the plot, with **y-value = 1** for **M1 (model1)**. I tried adding:

```
 geom_point(aes(y = 1, x = "M1"), color = "red", cex = 0.5)
```

but it doesn't work. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: worked for me.  What do you mean by doesn't work?

Comment: The point doesn't show-up :S:S

Comment: What's not working? It adds a point here...

Comment: was about to suggest the same

Comment: didn't forget the `+`... very odd

Comment: You may want to update the Q with the full command you've run, including the `geom_point` piece.

Comment: @BrodieG I just closed my R session and reopened it, and now it works.. so odd.. And then it works for two minutes, and stops working after that. Not sure what's wrong with it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cex` is not an argument for `geom_point`. Try `size`, e.g.

```
geom_point(aes(y = 1, x = "M1"), color = "red", size = 10)
```

[image]